# Apache - Do not serve root directory

Tags: apache-http-server, webserver

I'm trying to stop apache from serving my root directory, but setting deny from all to `<Directory />` also stops apache from serving /var/www/html. Even though access is allowed to that directory in the config.
**Apache config file:**

```
<Directory />
AllowOverride None
</Directory>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

#
# Relax access to content within /var/www.
#
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# Further relax access to the default document root:
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride None

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
    Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

Comment: If your `DocumentRoot` is set to `/var/www/html` why don't you want to allow access to that directory? If your content is in `/var/www/html/example` and you want to have the server use that directory as the top-level directory and not `/var/www/html`, you could change the value for `DocumentRoot` to `/var/www/html/example`.  If you are referring to the `/`, aka "root" directory, outside of Apache at the operating system level, Apache already won't provide access to it.

Comment: The set document root node is after the / directory